# Keep getting Undefined variable: DATABASE_URL error on Laravel - MySql

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-6

I keep getting

> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: DATABASE_URL in ....../config/database.php`

error when running

```
php artisan migrate:fresh --force`
```

My .env file consist of

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=xxxxx
DB_USERNAME=xxxxx
DB_PASSWORD=xxxx
DATABASE_URL=mysql://xxxxx:xxxxx@127.0.0.1:3306/xxxxx
```

I'm not sure why this is showing up.

Comment: You need to show your `....../config/database.php` file, where is tries to access the `DATABASE_URL`.

Comment: Here's my `./config/database.php` file

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [
    'connections' => [
        'sqllite' => [
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            ....
        ],
        'mysql' => [
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            ........
        ],
        'pgsql' => [
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            ..........
        ],
        'sqlsrv' => [
             'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
             ....
        ]
    ]
];
```

Comment: Why are you not using the default DB_HOST property, why are you defining a full mysql URL? Also: normally the php would state the line in which the error occurs. Show what that line looks like.

Comment: I actually had set DB_HOST, but the error was showing. Which was why I tried to set `DATABASE_URL`. The error occurred on the line 70 to 74 which corresponds to 
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', 'xxxx'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'xxxx'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'xxxx'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
for `pgsql`

Comment: Are you sure you pasted the correct code? I don't see any `DATABASE_URL` text. Also: why change the values of `pgsql` when you are not even using that? Your connection is set to `mysql` so there is no reason to edit the others.

Comment: I'm also baffled by it as well, because, as you can see from the question, I set mysql, but it says that the error is on pgsql's set of config. FYI - I didn't edit anything on `./config/database.php`

Answer (score 1):

Do use only one

**Either**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=xxxxx
DB_USERNAME=xxxxx
DB_PASSWORD=xxxx
```

**Or,**

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://xxxxx:xxxxx@127.0.0.1:3306/xxxxx
```

*DATABASE_URL contains all the database config, i.e. DB_CONNECTION, DB_HOST, etc.*